# What is sense terminal/pin in differential amplifiers?

Tags: amplifier, differential

I sometimes encounter a connection terminal called [AISENSE](https://www.ni.com/images/gettingstarted/neutral/hw_daq_1.gif) in some data acquisition boards. I also see a pin called SENSE in diff. and Instrumentation amplifiers.

An example(look at the pin called SENSE at the upper right corner):

[image]

Another example:

[image]

1-) What is the SENSE pin shown in the circuits above and what is it used for?

2-) Is SENSE same thing with AISENSE?

Comment: Possibly related https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/284135/what-is-the-sense-pin-on-an-op-amp

Answer (score 1):

As @Tyler pointed out in comments, this question has already been answered to some degree.

The short answer is that Sense is connected to Vo at its point of termination, or point of use, which could be inches away from the IC. The Sense pin detects voltage drop or inducted noise picked up by the Vo trace and cancels them out.

This way the end point of Vo has a clean and accurate signal. Of course Vo has a limit to its length of which the Sense pin can compensate. I would keep Vo under a few inches at most, and very short if near digital ICs.

EDIT: To clarify use of the Sense pin. Under normal circumstances the sense pin can be tied to the Vo pin at the IC. The Sense pin serves its purpose in circuits which need ultra accurate DC measurements or ultra low noise. If it was never needed it would not exist as an external pin.

Comment: "The Sense pin detects voltage drop " Its just a pin which is connected to Vout. How does it do all of these you say??

Comment: Sense pin and Out pin are wired. They are literally the same node. There is nothing between them. I dont understand what you mean.

Comment: I see, Sense is more accurate but Vout could be at the end of 10m  cable and may get distorted. Sense will let us know to verify or quantify noise/distortion. Is that correct? So in schematics they draw them next to each other that confused me. Vout could be after a long trace or cable. (?)

Comment: @JRE. Thanks for the corrections. I am now answering questions after more than a year and need to fine-tune my grammar.

Comment: @user134429. For long distance connections I used a SSM2142 600 ohm differential driver, with supply rails of +/- 18 VDC, over a shielded twisted pair cable. The Sense pin cannot cancel out large common-mode DC drift.

Comment: So you used +/-Force pins connected to SSM2142?

Comment: @user134429. *We have about used up our comment space allotted* but I do connect them at the SSM2142 IC, then run a close pair of equal length traces to a 3 pin header for the STP cable to plug into. The load (maybe 50 feet later) is a 1 K ohm .1% differential load into a differential op-amp. 100 K ohm resistors to ground keep the inputs from floating.